# Displaying content behind SystemTray on WP8/8.1 Silverlight (full screen background with visible and transparent SystemTray)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My question is for Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight.

I'm trying to apply a full screen background to a `PhoneApplicationPage`, but when I do so, SystemTray is blocking the view.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[image: Default office app on WP8 Silverlight]

As you can see, the default Office app on Windows Phone 8 (emulator) has a transparent background and the office logo behind it.  How can I achieve this?

I don't want to hide the SystemTray because this will be very inconvinient for the user.

I've gone through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnkenn/archive/2014/04/16/hiding-the-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-apps-or-not.aspx) article on MSDN Blog, but it deals with *Universal Apps* so APIs mentioned there are not available.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

1. Apply margin of `0,-32,0,0` to top of your `LayoutRoot` Grid.
2. Add a positive margin of `32` to existing top margin of first child element (to balance step 1).
3. Set `SystemTray.Opacity = 0.001` (see **edit0**) in `OnLoaded` event of the page to make SystemTray transparent.

This will shift your entire screen Grid upward (and hide behind the SystemTray). Then setting opacity of SystemTray to 0.001 makes background transparent.

Partial code:

> Step 1 & 2

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent"

      Margin="0,-32,0,0"> <!-- Step 1 -->

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/SampleImage.png" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"

                Margin="12,49,0,28"> <!--Step 2. (default Margin="12,17,0,28")-->

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="lel k"
                   Margin="9,-7,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

> Step 3

```
public partial class Page1: PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
        //...
    }

    void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemTray.Opacity = 0.001; // see edit0
    }
}
```

And done!
Happy Coding :)

**edit0:**

Seems like setting `SystemTray.Opacity = 0.0` hides *Battery Indicator* and *Cellular Signal*. Changing it to `SystemTray.Opacity = 0.001` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two great blog posts (very humble brag) about extending your app theme into the System tray:

- [Extending your app theme into the SystemTray](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/03/10/Extending-your-app-theme-into-the-SystemTray.aspx)
- [Place your app title in the System Tray](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/02/11/Place-your-app-title-in-the-System-Tray.aspx)

To accomplish what you want to do simply change the Opacity of the SystemTray to anything less than 1. Doing this will shift all content up into the tray. From there you can play with the Background or Opacity to back the color you want. If you just want it to be completely transparent, set the Opacity to 0. This will however have an [adverse effect on Windows Phone 8.1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/925443/connections-icons-will-not-show-in-windows-phone-8-1-for-windows-phone-8-app-with-opaque-system-tray).

Comment: Settings opacity to 0.001 solves the adverse effect on WP8.1 :)

Comment: Yes, but this is a functional change from 8 to 8.1 and as such should be fixed by MS

Comment: Yeah they should, I was just telling for others who read your answer and stuck with opacity=0 problem

Answer (score -1):

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow)
```